# how to avoid duplicate download urls in my python spider program?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I wrote a spider program with python. It can recursively crawl web pages. I want to avoid download the same pages, so I store the urls in a list as follow:

```
urls = []
def download(mainPage):  # mainPage is a link
    global urls
    links = getHrefLinks(mainPage)
    for l in links:
        if l not in urls:
            urls.append(l)
            downPage(l)
```

But there is a problem that when the links are too much, the urls will be very large, and the efficiency of the code `if l not in urls` is low. How to solve the problem? What is the best way to  avoid duplicate download urls without taking too much memory and improve the efficiency?

Comment: make `urls` a `set`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: It might be worthwhile taking a look at Scrapy: http://scrapy.org/ It can crawl without downloading the same pages multiple times, multi-threads, plus a ton of other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make urls into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
urls = set()
def download(mainPage):  # mainPage is a link
    global urls
    links = getHrefLinks(mainPage)
    for l in links:
        if l not in urls:
            urls.add(l) #instead of append
            downPage(l)
```

Lookups of objects, i.e., `x in s` are, in the [average case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), of complexity O(1), which is better than the average case of the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, as you iterate over your URL results you could store them in a dictionary. 
The key of this dictionary would be the url, the value could be a boolean if you've seen the url before. In the end print the keys of this dict and it would have all unique urls.

Also, doing the lookup via a dict will give you O(1) time when checking if the URL has been seen or not.

```
# Store mapping of {URL: Bool}
url_map = {}

# Iterate over url results
for url in URLs:
    if not url_map.get(url, False):
        url_map[url] = True

# Values of dict will have all unique urls 
print(url_maps.keys())
```